# How can ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{{2^n}+1}{3^n}}={\frac{5}{2}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I use online tool to calculate this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{{2^n}+1}{3^n}$$

And the result is $\frac{5}{2}$.

I try to split them into $A={\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{{2^n}}{3^n}}}=2$ and $B={\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{3^n}}}=5$. So $A+B=7$, different with the result from calculator.

Could you please help me to explain why it's $\frac{5}{2}$. This is my homework and Im really bad with math.

Thank you very much.

**Update:** the result of **B** is $0.5$, not $5$. I have big mistake. Thank you for all the reply!!

Comment: You might write the summand as $(2/3)^n + (1/3)^n$, the use your knowledge of geometric series.

Comment: Probably best not to readily admit that you are "really stupid", @Valentine, unless you want pity votes, which makes you look like you're a cheater.

Comment: @amWhy I know you are great man who have a high rep. But it not mean you can judging others like that. I dont want to get rep because of that, and I dont think others will vote because of that too. That comment is just because I have a big mistake so need to post this question here. If I am more carefull, I do not need to do that

Comment: @Valentine.  I am not a great ***man,*** and I hardly have high rep. (And please don't assume every user on this site is a ***man***).  But please, ask decent questions, and please, more than anything, don't ever call yourself stupid.  No one should ever call themselves *stupid*. Hold your head up high!

Comment: @amWhy oh sorry, I did not mean you are a man when said "man". About the "stupid" thing, all I mean is my action, but I have expressed it incorrectly. Btw, why you so serious about it? In my country, it's not bad if we sometimes blame ourselves. In that situation, it's just an exclamative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Remember that, for any $|x|<1$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac x{1-x}.$$

Comment: thank you so much. It's a good hint

Answer (score -1):

Write it as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+\frac{1}{3^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^n}$$
And you can evaluate them because they are two geometric series, which sums are known.

Comment: thank you. It's help me a lot